# Setting default value to a "create form"

Tags: php, forms, yii

I have a create form called Form-1a, what i was trying to do is to create a form-1a and when it is created and you view it there will be a link adding a new form called home visit, now what i want to do is when i create that form "home visit" a certain field in form-1a will be a default value to the create form of Home Visit ... my question is how to do that? I haven't started on anything yet.

Form-1a-> create -> created -> click add home visit link -> in family code of home visit -> set created form-1a family code in homevisit family code

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are going to use a Yii CModel or CActiveRecord model. If so, after you have instantiated it in your controller, set the attribute you want to your default setting.

You can also setup some default settings for your model in its `init` method and it will work across multiple forms by default.